# Define type based on super class constructor parameter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type based on superclass' constructor parameter.

**Is there a way to extract it without defining own constructor as it's not really needed?**

**`somelib/BaseClass.ts`**

```js
export default abstract class BaseClass {
  constructor(protected options: { key: string }) {}
}
```

**`src/AClass.ts`**

```js
import BaseClass from 'somelib/BaseClass';

export default class AClass extends BaseClass {}
```

**`src/index.ts`**

```js
import AClass from './AClass.ts'

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type ConstructorFirstParameter<T extends Constructor<any>> = T extends new (
  options: infer O,
  ...rest: any
) => any
  ? O
  : never;


type Options = ConstructorFirstParameter<AClass>
```

And I'm receiving an error

```
Type 'AClass' does not satisfy the constraint 'Constructor<any>'.
  Type 'AClass' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): any'.ts(2344)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I've missed `typeof AClass`

```
import AClass from './AClass.ts'

type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type ConstructorFirstParameter<T extends Constructor<any>> = T extends new (
  options: infer O,
  ...rest: any
) => any
  ? O
  : never;


type Options = ConstructorFirstParameter<typeof AClass>
```

[working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8AoBJAewDtIoBXeSqACgAcpKId4cATBJTYQAljTAAuEggDWOAJ5S6I6gHMEAXwCUJDaT2kUaDAEECxhDgAe3anwzYw%20QhmIHSEeWxwI846IwQzAA8ACoAfAgAvAjUOADuCCwAdKnAUKqSCMDU8gDaALo6UZGhANykHl4%20frQBTFAAYiJQkAAK6cAAtjjcUGGWNjh2GLV0gSE58uGRMaGDtvaxCUnkgsJitFIqAGY4UAgA8gA0a6nJUDiQUlOkxZG3FAD8R2tScQBu%20xWVnt5HG3E0V8-gYDWarQgHRgPT6wT%20OEoOwQZhc4UqsH86wgWUOgNowLIFDkigQAHJuJAyfogA)